# What is the use of credentials file in multi-user samba?

Tags: samba, cifs

I am trying to understand how samba works. I found out there are two types of sharing, single-user and multi-user. I am confused about what is the specific difference between the two? Does single-user sharing mean that whenever the share is mounted by a single user, any other user cannot mount that same share? And is it the opposite in multi-user samba?

Also why do we need a credentials file? What is its use? And why do we use this file only for multi-user sharing?

I am having a hard time understanding these concepts. Any lead is appreciated.
Also I do not have much experience asking questions here on stack exchange, please excuse the formatting of this question.
Many thanks.

Comment: After a lot of research I found that credentials file is used to mount the share at the boot time by using the credentials of the mentioned user in the file.